# Next / Previous months not showing in codeigniter 3.0 Calendar

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter Calendar version 3.0 Library for new advantage, and the issue is not displaying next and previous months, it shows not found exception.

My sample code is

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->display($year = null, $month = null);
    }
     public function display($year = null, $month = null)
    {
            $config = array(
            'show_next_prev' => TRUE,
            'show_other_days' => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url' => base_url().'welcome/display'
            );
            $this->load->library('calendar', $config);
            echo $data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);

    }
}
```

I configured database.php and routes.php(helper('url')).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `base_url().'welcome/display'`

Use `site_url('welcome/display')`

CI runs through index.php - The base_url function returns the path to the root directory. (this is good for including stylesheets, or whatever)

The site_url function returns the site URL (with index.php)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not Working Next Prev Option in Calendar

```
$config = array(
    'show_next_prev' => TRUE,
    'next_prev_url' =>site_url('user/events')
);
$this->load->library('calendar', $config);
echo $this->calendar->generate();
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your Answer, please rephrase your explanation to explain what was causing the problem from the Question and how your Answer addresses that problem.